# Chain of methods in rails ( call methods by step)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, design-patterns

I try to find how to best way implement chain of methods in Ruby( Rails application) 
like this

```
class Foo
  attr_accessor :errors
  attr_accessor :shared_params

  def initialize(..)
    ..
  end

  def call 
    check_params
    calc_smthing
    write_in_db
  end

  prviate

  def check_params
    ..
  end

  def calc_smthing
    ..
  end

  def write_in_db
    ..
  end
end
```

main ideas:

- if something fail( or not fail but return false) in some step others steps doesnt call, 
  of course I dont want to add multiple ifs to check state and think about how implement it in one place
- I need to save errors
- It would be great to find way to share params between methods.

I can write in simple( ugly) way with ifs 
but I try to find more elegant way or pattern because problem not so specific I think.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is a http://trailblazer.to/ gem/framework which implements the pattern you're looking for. It has `Operation` class, which has multiple steps, which can return either `success` or `failure`. More info you're able to find on official site.

Comment: @nattfodd Thank you for answer. But I try to find way remove trailblaizer  from my application.

Comment: Why don't you find out how does trailblazer team implement Operation and do it your self?

Answer (score 0):

Save errors and shared attributes to variables (how you do it now). Unite methods to chain of methods:

```
def call 
  check_params && calc_smthing && write_in_db
end

def valid?
  errors.blank?
end
```